# Is there a formulaic or other way of determining the relative/normative value of the daily nutrition requirements?

Tags: nutrition

Take [this list](http://www.fda.gov/Food/GuidanceRegulation/GuidanceDocumentsRegulatoryInformation/LabelingNutrition/ucm064928.htm) of suggested daily intake for example.  Now assume you cannot for economic reasons achieve 100% on all of these items.  Say you're sitting at 50% for carbs, 50% for vitamin A, and 50% for calcium for the day in one particular example to illustrate my overall question.  You have one more dollar left in your pocket and you can buy one of these nutrition choices which result in:

A) (+25% carb, +25% vitamin A, +10% calcium)

B) (+25% carb, +10% vitamin A, +25% calcium)

C) (+5% carb, +45% vitamin A, +45% calcium)

D) (+45% carb, +5% vitamin A, +5% calcium)

E) (+20% carb, +20% vitamin A, +20% calcium)

Which is the healthiest of these choices for the average homo sapiens, and in general, how do you figure out the answer to this kind of problem so I know what to do in other examples?

Comment: It varies so much on personal requirements. The FDA diet is not the only way to consume macronutrients. Keto (low/0-carb) is a valid way to live your life healthily. Absorption of vitamins and minerals depends heavily on each other as well.

Comment: @JJosaur - I'm not interested in what is "valid."  To better explain, I am interested in what is cheap.  If you tell me that (all carbs + no meat) is just as valid as (all meat + no carbs) in that case all I need to know is which costs more, meat or carbs.  I can handle the shopping.  I just need you to tell me which of the above choices are better, worse, or equally valid and how to determine that.

Comment: If money is the big driver then you can easily hit your macro and micro nutrients while eat frugally. That said, energy comes from calories (proteins, fats and carbs) so focus on those mainly. The micros should follow unless you are using food supplements.

Comment: @JJosaur - What if I gave you $100 and presented you with 10 different items to choose from and I told you to maximize health subject to that $100.   I guess what you're saying is there is probably more than one solution to this constrained optimization problem.  But in any case, there is a thought process you would use to arrive at your conclusions.  Is that thought process articulable?